# How to retrieve data related to helper methods of a jQueryUI sortable list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, list

I am using jQueryUI 1.8.14 and I would like to understand how to use helper methods related to a [jQueryUI sortable list](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable):

```
ui.helper - the current helper element (most often a clone of the item)
ui.position - current position of the helper
ui.offset - current absolute position of the helper
ui.item - the current dragged element
ui.placeholder - the placeholder (if you defined one)
ui.sender - the sortable where the item comes from (only exists if you move from one connected list to another)
```

For example, if I run the `alert(ui.position)` like the following

```
$jQ("#sortable").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.position)
  }
});
```

I get an alert message like this: "`[object Object]`"... **how can I inspect that object** (eg: in order to retrieve the position value - that is, an integer value)**?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use console.log on it, then you can see what the object contains :)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    alert("top:" + ui.position.top + " left:" + ui.position.left);
  }
});
```

Found this by doing: `console.log(ui.position);`

Result: `Object { top=26, left=10}`